# How should the Fabric deployment work If I'm using Django on Heroku with Django-South?

Tags: django, heroku, fabric, django-south

I want to use Fabric so I can wrap all my production deployment steps:

- git push to heroku
- South migrations
- collectstatic for static files to S3

I'm assuming that for the git push to heroku and the collectstatic I can just put their commands into a fabfile, correct? How would South migrations work?

Comment: I've done a lot with Django, South and Fabric. Haven't worked with Heroku, but the key question is how would you do this without Fabric? South makes it easy to run migrations by simply running "manage.py migrate." Fabric makes it easy to run that on remote servers by connecting to that server and then using something like "run('manage.py migrate')." If this was on EC2, that'd be it. However, Heroku is more managed than that, so the question is what's the command in Heroku to execute the "manage.py migrate" there?

I bet something similar will do the trick for static files.

Comment: I can run python commands with "heroku run python project/manage.py", but its still a manual deployment process with at least 3 steps right now. Its not a huge deal, but at some point integration with Fabric might make sense for streamlining deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just wrap the commands in a shell script?

```
deploy.sh

git push heroku master
heroku run python project/manage.py migrate
# Collect static command - not sure if you want to do this locally or from Heroku
```